# Sqlite Playing Cards Table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm learning SQL by using Sqlite. I want to create a simple deck of playing cards using Sqlite. My attempt is below.

Because I kept getting syntax errors I tried letting `DB browser for Sqlite` create the code to create the table by adding the fields manually. Now I'm left with some kind of hybrid syntax and I can't identify what the problems is when I put it through a syntax checker.

If I try and insert just one line:

```
INSERT INTO cards (name, suit, suit_symbol, score) VALUES (

    -- Spades
    ("A", "spades", "♠", 1)
  );
```

I get `Uncaught Error: 1 values for 4 columns`

If I try and run the whole thing, I get `Uncaught Error: near ")": syntax error`

I'm guessing there's at least two problems with my code, and part of the difficulty is that I have already learned a little MySQL which seems to be subtly and confusingly different.

Any help with getting my table built successfully in Sqlite and understanding why it doesn't work as is would be much appreciated.

```
--CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS cards;

CREATE TABLE IF not exists "cards" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "name"  TEXT,
    "suit"  TEXT,
    "suit_symbol"   TEXT,
    "score" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO cards (name, suit, suit_symbol, score) VALUES (

    -- Spades
    ("A", "spades", "♠", 1), 
    ("2", "spades", "♠", 2), 
    ("3", "spades", "♠", 3), 
    ("4", "spades", "♠", 4), 
    ("5", "spades", "♠", 5), 
    ("6", "spades", "♠", 6), 
    ("7", "spades", "♠", 7), 
    ("8", "spades", "♠", 8), 
    ("9", "spades", "♠", 9), 
    ("10", "spades", "♠", 10), 
    ("J", "spades", "♠", 11), 
    ("Q", "spades", "♠", 12), 
    ("K", "spades", "♠", 13), 

    -- Hearts
    ("A", "hearts", "♥", 1), 
    ("2", "hearts", "♥", 2), 
    ("3", "hearts", "♥", 3), 
    ("4", "hearts", "♥", 4), 
    ("5", "hearts", "♥", 5), 
    ("6", "hearts", "♥", 6), 
    ("7", "hearts", "♥", 7), 
    ("8", "hearts", "♥", 8), 
    ("9", "hearts", "♥", 9), 
    ("10", "hearts", "♥", 10), 
    ("J", "hearts", "♥", 11), 
    ("Q", "hearts", "♥", 12), 
    ("K", "hearts", "♥", 13), 

    -- Clubs
    ("A", "clubs", "♣", 1), 
    ("2", "clubs", "♣", 2), 
    ("3", "clubs", "♣", 3), 
    ("4", "clubs", "♣", 4), 
    ("5", "clubs", "♣", 5), 
    ("6", "clubs", "♣", 6), 
    ("7", "clubs", "♣", 7), 
    ("8", "clubs", "♣", 8), 
    ("9", "clubs", "♣", 9), 
    ("10", "clubs", "♣", 10), 
    ("J", "clubs", "♣", 11), 
    ("Q", "clubs", "♣", 12), 
    ("K", "clubs", "♣", 13), 

    -- Diamonds
    ("A", "diamonds", "♦", 1), 
    ("2", "diamonds", "♦", 2), 
    ("3", "diamonds", "♦", 3), 
    ("4", "diamonds", "♦", 4), 
    ("5", "diamonds", "♦", 5), 
    ("6", "diamonds", "♦", 6), 
    ("7", "diamonds", "♦", 7), 
    ("8", "diamonds", "♦", 8), 
    ("9", "diamonds", "♦", 9), 
    ("10", "diamonds", "♦", 10), 
    ("J", "diamonds", "♦", 11), 
    ("Q", "diamonds", "♦", 12), 
    ("K", "diamonds", "♦", 13), 
    );
```

Comment: Did you try to give 4 values instead of one value in the shape of a pair of `()` i.e. `INSERT INTO cards (name, suit, suit_symbol, score) VALUES ("A", "spades", "♠", 1  );`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be outer parenthesis around the tuples for values. Just a tuple is surrounded by parenthesis, multiple ones are separated by a comma.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO cards
            (name,
             suit,
             suit_symbol,
             score)
            VALUES ('A', 'spades', '♠', 1), 
                   ('2', 'spades', '♠', 2),
                   ...
                   ('K', 'diamonds', '♦', 13);
```

And by the way: The proper quotes for string literals in SQL are single quotes. Double quotes are for identifiers. Though some DBMS accept to interchange them, it's a good idea to get used to the standard way, which is more likely to be cross platform.